# Is it possible to install the Plex Media Server on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, media

I New to Raspberry PI (and I have a Raspberry Pi 2) and have Raspbian running on it.

- Is it possible to install Plex Media Server?
- If not is there a better way of using it to stream media?

Comment: Thanks to incredible new internet technology an answer may be at your fingertips: [LMGTFY](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=plex+media+server+raspberry+pi).

Comment: It is [possible](http://www.htpcguides.com/install-plex-media-server-on-raspberry-pi-2/) but expect preposterous encoding times.

Comment: Watching LMGTFY just burned 3 gallons of oil powering all the data centres involved :D jjesse ... Did you get something working? Pi3 seems to be able to do it now. I am changing the subject to be more generic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Uglymagoo website to download his port! It just works!

Here is the original place where it appeared.

https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/comment/903212/#Comment_903212

I actually discovered through here:

http://www.htpcguides.com/install-plex-media-server-on-raspberry-pi-2/

I didn't change locales or anything.

Looking my `history`, what I did type was the below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
wget -O - https://dev2day.de/pms/dev2day-pms.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Are you running wheezy or jessie? Use `cat /etc/*-release` and download the appropriate!

```
echo "deb https://dev2day.de/pms/ wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plexmediaserver
```

Add plex to you group! (mine is `pi`!)

```
MYGROUP=$USER
sudo usermod -a -G $MYGROUP plex
sudo service plexmediaserver restart
```

On a note I've read that Uglymagoo is not updating the Wheezy repository anymore, but at the moment everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

**Clients**

You can get the [Plex client for Raspberry at RasPlex](http://www.rasplex.com/) which is optimised for rendering playback but it will also play video via any HTML5 enabled browser via the WebGUI.

**Server for Raspberry Pi 3**

Now with the Raspberry 3 we have an option of running a Plex server. There are no official arm packages but you can download pre-built Plex server packages. Please follow one of these two guides.

- [Element14 Guide](https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberrypi_projects/blog/2016/03/11/a-more-powerful-plex-media-server-using-raspberry-pi-3)
- [PiMyLifeUp](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-plex-server/)

**Server Raspberry Pi 2,1**

Unfortunately, on older Pi's even if you got it running on the Pi the best you could do is DirectPlay or DirectStream. And you have would have some bandwidth issues depending on how you were storing the files.

Transcoding of any kind will be terrible because the is no GPU pass-through support.. .and it would only support x264 (which is majority of the case so its not that bad, but there is no support)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Plex Media Center, so the question is: what special things does the (partly closed) Plex Media Server do...?
but with [RasPlex](http://www.rasplex.com/) there is a special Plex Home Theater port for the Raspberry Pi.

Nevertheless I would advise you to install [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/), [XBian](http://www.xbian.org/) or any other version of [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/)/Debian and then you can use the usual (standardized and open source) tools, protocols and services to interact with nearly every media center (most of them are anyway based on [Kodi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodi_%28software%29#Derivatives_and_forks) like Plex)!

Comment: -1, the question was not about Plex Media **Center**, rather it was about Plex Media **Server**, and as far as I can tell, Plex is in no way based on Kodi.

Comment: 1) "If not is there a better way of using it to stream media?" - I told what's only possible with Raspberry Pi and Plex... and gave a (better) server-alternative to interact with several media center clients!

Comment: 2) [**Plex Media Center** and **Plex Home Theater**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plex_%28software%29) are definitely [based on XBMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_based_on_Kodi_and_XBMC#Plex) which was renamed to Kodi!

Comment: Yes, Plex Media **Center/Theater** are based on XMBC/Kodi.  However, if you read the rest of the link you posted, you will see that Plex Media **Server** is mostly proprietary code.

Comment: yes, and that's why i suggested to use **Debian** or a other Debian based minimal distribution **for the server** to interact via standardized and open protocols with nearly every **client** (like the **Kodi based Plex**)!